# Python .Как в условии if указать , что ключа словаря может не быть

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь получить данные через api VK о пользователях, в одних случаях есть поле book , в другом нет, и компилятор ругается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в условии if прописать вариант когда нет этого атрибута?

```
vk = session.get_api()
l=vk.users.search(count=1000,sort=0,fields='books,can_write_private_message,music', city=159, sex=1, has_photo=True,birth_day=1,birth_month=12
                  )

for i in range(1000):
    if len(l['items'][i]['book'])!=0:
        print(f'{i} '+str(l['items'][i]['book']))
```

Comment: `if not 'key' in dictionary:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так нужно делать:

```
d = {'Name': 'Vasia'}
# метод get возвращает значение по ключу
# если такого ключа нет возвращает None
if d.get('Name'):
    print(d.get('Name'))
else:
    print('Такого ключа не существует')

#---------------------------------------

for i in range(1000):
if l['items'][i].get('book'):
    print(f'{i} '+str(l['items'][i].get('book')))
```

Comment: Точку перед последним `get` потеряли

Answer (score 2):

Наличие ключа в словаре проверяется оператором `in`:

```
if 'book' in l['items'][i]:
    pass
```

Либо not in:

```
if 'book' not in l['items'][i]:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно например через `.keys()` проверку делать:

```python
if 'book' in l['items'][i].keys():
    Do something
```

Comment: `.keys()` вообще не нужно, обычно обращение к словарю подразумевает перебор его ключей

Comment: @CrazyElf да, не нужно. Так нагляднее.